# Django mysql when saving a object got warning

Tags: mysql, django

I was just writing a little app to store words in my mysql database using Django.I read data from a text file which is extremely well organised,like this:
The text file is like this:

```
DELUGE
DELUSION
DELVE
DEMAGOGUE
DEMANDING
DEMOLITION
DEMONSTRATE
DEMORALIZE
DEMOTIC
DEMUR
DENIGRATE
DENOUEMENT
DENOUNCE
DENT
DENUDE
DEPLETE
DEPLORE
DEPLOY
```

And then I read date from it using open('thefile').readlines like this:

```
 for line in open('/home/jacos/sorted-gre.txt').readlines():
...     if line:
...         p = Word(word_spelling = line)
...         p.save()
```

The word_spelling field is the primary key.
Then came this warning:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 553, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1436, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 791, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
  Data truncated for column 'word_spelling' at row 1
```

As a result, only part of these words were stored in mysql. I'd like to know why.

Comment: You're missing the last line(s) in your traceback… The line(s) which show exactly which error was being raised. Can you add those?

Comment: @DavidWolever Warning: Data truncated for column 'word_spelling' at row 1.sorry about that.

Comment: Please post the model definition for `Word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CharFields have a max_length attribute. What did you set when you generate database
for `Word.object.get(pk=1).word_spelling`?

nothing related with your warning but
it's recommended to close file or open it with a `with` statement.

```
with open('/home/jacos/sorted-gre.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line:
            p = Word(word_spelling = line)
            p.save()
```

Comment: oops.I forgot that the max_length has been set to 20 and I found there were words longer than that.(By mistake.)So problem solved.Thanks for help.